# What is this popup in Gnome 40?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-event

I'm trying to understand the meaning of those popups:

[image]

[image]

Those are triggered by a button of a remote which evtest interprets as F21:

```
Event: time 1635529094.562219, type 17 (EV_LED), code 0 (LED_NUML), value 0
Event: time 1635529094.562219, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70070
Event: time 1635529094.562219, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 191 (KEY_F21), value 1
Event: time 1635529094.562219, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1635529094.578132, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70070
Event: time 1635529094.578132, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 191 (KEY_F21), value 0
Event: time 1635529094.578132, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

xev grabs no keycodes.

Comment: it does look like it's telling you your touchpad has been activated or deactivated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller +1 ... the popup may be from the laptop hardware, not from linux

Comment: @jsotola it *also* does look a lot like's Gnome's standard icon theme... Almost certain it's a gnome thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that was the touchpad activation icon. I removed the value in dconf (which toggled "XF86TouchpadOn/Off") and gained access to the button mapping within Kodi (which was the initial goal). This media-keys plugin should be shipped with blank values.